# PHP preg_grep -> search array where search term contains special character

Tags: php, arrays, preg-grep

Trying to search an array that contains special characters:

```
$array=array("0|0Name"=>"first name","0|1last"=>"last name","1|0email"=>"email address");
```

tried

```
  $v="0|0";
  print_r(preg_grep("/^".$v.".*/",$array)); --->FAIL
```

tried:

```
  $v=str_replace("|","\|","0|0");
  print_r(preg_grep("/^".$v.".*/",$array)); --->FAIL
```

Comment: what do you want to return?

Comment: an array with the keys to reference the $array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_quote()`, it will escape the special characters, taking into account the delimiter (in your case, `/`):

```
$v = preg_quote("0|0", "/");
print_r(preg_grep("/^".$v.".*/",$array));
```

Comment: Thats it! Thanks. Also found that I need to change $array to array_keys($array) to actually find anything :)